# Fixing go imports to relative instead of absolute path

Tags: go, gofmt

Is there a tool that could change the imports across my package from absolute path to a relative path. 
Currently my import for `package bar` look like this :

```
import FOO_common/server/src/foo/bar
```

I want to convert this to

```
import foo/bar
```

Is there a tool like `gofmt` that could do this for me ? I know I can solve this with bash `sed`. However, am hoping for a `go tool` that might exist out there for the same.

Comment: `foo/bar` is not a relative path - Go assumes that imports are rooted in `GOPATH/src`. A relative path would be "./foo/bar", but that's likely not what you want, and you would have to use a different import statement depending on where each file is in your hierarchy. You probably want to stick with normal imports.

Comment: You really do not want to use relative import paths. They are not supported in all cases by the Go tooling, and just meant for quick, on-off tests.

Comment: @Adrian My mistake ... I did mean `$GOPATH/src/foo/bar` provided `$GOPATH` points to my project directory

Comment: Then that's not a relative path - as far as Go is concerned, that's a normal import path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 gofmt -w -r '"FOO_common/server/src/foo/bar" -> "foo/bar"' *.go
```

This will just look for the strings as they are, and replace them with the new string.

If you need more advanced functionality such as wildcards, you might want to look at this other tool:

https://github.com/rogpeppe/govers

Comment: I tried this. Is there a way to wildcard and replace things ? FOO_common/server/src/<*> -> <*> ?

Comment: edited my answer to answer that as well